# How can I create an email autoresponder app using Amazon SES/web services?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

NOTE: I originally posted this in Super User but some felt it was off-topic there. Here was the next most relevant place I could think of.

I want to make a service that works like this:

1. User emails jokebot@domain.com,
2. Bot fetches next joke from joke server (maybe hosted on EC2),
3. Bot replies (via email) to user with joke.

But I'm not sure what’s the best way to approach making this app. If it were your project, how would you set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Set up an email receiver in your SES dashboard. Assign it to trigger a SNS event on each email received.

Then, you'd have an AWS lambda function, which gets called on a new SNS event for the specific topic. This Lambda function would act as your transponder.